# Reading Data from different dimension when creating MDX queries in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a query but it utilizes two different dimensions. I receive this error "Members, tuples, or sets must use the same hierarchies in the function." I've run this with/without the brackets in the row section and got the same error. How do I resolve this issue?
[Error Message/MDX Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sva4g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different hierarchies of the same dimension `[Dim Course]` in the tuple which is not allowed.

You will have to change your query, something like this should work:

```
select {[Measures].[Dim Course Count],[Measures].[Dim Semester Count]} on 0,
{([Dim Course].[Course Code].[Course Code], [Dim Semester].[Academic Year].[Academic Year]) } on 1
from [CCSE-DM]
where [Dim Course].[Level1].[Level1]
```

Comment: @T.Com glad it helped. If the problem is solved you can mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.